# StackExchange.Redis StringGet Timeouts

Tags: asp.net, azure, caching, redis, stackexchange.redis

**Disclaimer**: I am quite new to Redis and StackExchange.Redis client.

**Scenario**: I've got an ASP.NET MVC web app that uses [ASP.NET Session State Provider for Azure Redis Cache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn690522.aspx).

This works like a charm!

Now, my controllers call my services layer (it's just a DLL reference but may become a Web Api call one day). I am trying to configure my redis client with Autofac as per below:

```
        var redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["redis.connectionstring"]);
        builder.RegisterInstance(redis).AsSelf().SingleInstance();
        builder.RegisterType<RedisCacheClient>().As<ICacheClient>().WithParameter("db", redis.GetDatabase());
```

The connection is set up successfully and I can see a new client when I run *client list* on *redis-cli.exe*.

My RedisCacheClient class is just a thin wrapper on [IDatabase](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/StackExchange.Redis/StackExchange/Redis/IDatabase.cs):

```
    public void Add(string key, object value)
    {
        _db.StringSet(key, Serialize(value));
    }

    public T Get<T>(string key)
    {
        byte[] buffer = _db.StringGet(key);
        T o = Deserialize<T>(buffer);
        return o;
    }

    private static byte[] Serialize(object o)
    {
        if (o == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Cannot cache null values.");
        }
        var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            binaryFormatter.Serialize(memoryStream, o);
            byte[] buffer = memoryStream.ToArray();
            return buffer;
        }
    }

    private static T Deserialize<T>(byte[] stream)
    {
        if (stream == null)
        {
            return default(T);
        }
        var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(stream))
        {
            T result = (T)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(memoryStream);
            return result;
        }
    }
```

**Problem**: I can store objects successfully but can never retrieve then! I keep getting connections timeout no matter what I do (current timeout is 30 secs).
I've spent the last 4 hours trying to figure this out and no luck. Really struggling :(

Some of the resources I have already gone through:
http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/02/10/investigating-timeout-exceptions-in-stackexchange-redis-for-azure-redis-cache/

[Timeout performing SET {Key}, inst: 0, mgr: Inactive, queue: 2, qu=1, qs=1, qc=0, wr=1/1, in=0/0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26727762/timeout-performing-set-key-inst-0-mgr-inactive-queue-2-qu-1-qs-1-qc-0)

[StackExchange.Redis with Azure Redis is unusably slow or throws timeout errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25416562/stackexchange-redis-with-azure-redis-is-unusably-slow-or-throws-timeout-errors)

[Azure Redis cache - timeouts on GET calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26489197/azure-redis-cache-timeouts-on-get-calls)

https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/122

https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/83

P.S: I get the very same behaviour running this locally or on azure.

Comment: What sort of size data are you storing as an individual string? (I'm trying to assess whether I should *expect* this to fail or not; I'm assuming "not", but worth asking)

Comment: Pretty small data actually. Tried a string like "foo", then a bool value, then a simple User object with FirstName and LastName as public properties. It's interesting because I can see all keys/values stored and retrieve then quite quickly using the command line.

Comment: more info @MarcGravell: When I do db.StringSet("foo", "bar") and then db.StringGet("foo") I consistently get: **Timeout performing GET foo, inst: 1, mgr: ExecuteSelect, queue: 2, qu: 2, qs: 0, qc: 0, wr: 0, wq: 1, in: 0, ar: 0, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=2,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=2,Free=4093,Min=2,Max=4095)**

Comment: Can you share your connection string (minus password) so that we can look at all your settings?

Answer (score 0):

As much as I truly dislike this I have to say that the issue is long gone and I ***have no idea why.*** 
I believe this was some sort of intermittent issue related to my setup (MacBook Pro running windows on a parallels VM) which might have been maxed out at times making Redis reject or not process items on its queue. Well, that's the only thing I could come up with since I have been running the same software for days now and have not had any issues.